# type error in python

Tags: python, types, absolute-value

I have a list of ints (hitTableWord) and I am trying to add 1 over the absolute value of the numbers for the whole list and I keep getting this error message in python:  metric = metric + 1/(abs(metricNumber))
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'type' and 'float'. metric was initialized as: metric = 0

Thing is I am a rookie programmer and don't know what it means.

```
 for a in range (0, len(hitTableWord)):
         output_file.write('Hit Word: '+ str(hitTableWord[a]) +' ' + str(hitTableNear[a])+ ', ')
         metric = metric + 1/(abs(hitTableWord[a]))
```

Any help would be appreciated. As usual with my questions I am sure it is something ridiculously simple that I just do not know about. So thanks for all your patience.

Comment: `metric` is not initialized in your example.  What is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like `metric` is a class you have defined somewhere, rather than an instance - ie, you have something like:

```
class metric(object):
    pass
```

You would need to call `metric()` to get an instance of it. Note that you'll continue to get a very similar error if `metric` doesn't define `__add__`.

Likewise, you may have inadvertently done:

```
metric = someclass
```

when you meant:

```
metric = someclass()
```

Either way, the error message is saying that `metric` contains a *class*, and Python doesn't know how to add classes to floats (or, for that matter, to anything much).

Also:

```
for a in range (0, len(hitTableWord)):
```

Is something you usually don't need to do in Python. Here you're using it because you need to access the relevant element of both `hitTableWord` and `hitTableNear` - you can do this more idiomatically as:

```
for word, near in zip(hitTableWord, hitTableNear):
```

Comment: @Will indeed. In fact, leaving the `()` off an assignment like that is probably a more likely error than `class metric`. I've updated my answer to include that case.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Also, the info on the loop is quite helpful. Thank-you

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that `hitTableWord` only contains numbers, can you take a look at where you define metric? The error means that you are trying to add two different types of variables together, and that Python can not perform this operation for the given types, similar to how you can not add strings to integers, or concatenate integers to strings.

As an example:

```
5 + "abc"
```

Here, the plus works as arithmetic operator, this does not work with strings.

```
"abc" + 5
```

Here, the plus indicates string concatenation, this does not work with integers.

Answer (score 0):

You write that metric with initialized with 0. But I suppose that it is not so. You have a value of type `type` in the `metric` variable. And that is the problem here.

Comment: Igor, you are right. I had it defined as a float. It works now thanks

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
from itertools import izip

metric = 0.
for tw,tn in izip(hitTableWord, hitTableNear):
    output_file.write("Hit Word: {} {}".format(tw,tn))
    metric += 1./abs(tw)
```